# After looping through checkboxes with a .each() it wont allow me to recheck the box

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have the following jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.xRgn .xInner .col .xOB', function(event){
    clickedDiv = $(this);

    clickedDiv.parents('.col').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr("checked", false);
    });

    clickedDiv.find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("checked", true);
});
```

As you can see I am attempting to make checkboxes behave as Radio Buttons (It is impossible to change the HTML in this scenario).

I first deselect all of the checkboxes and then reselect the checkbox inside of the div that was clicked.

It deselects the checkboxes just fine, however it doesn't re-select the clicked checkbox.  If I remove the `.each loop` it does select the checkbox inside of the div.

Any ideas why it's not working as expected?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that the value for the checked attribute is not true or false, but checked or empty string.

You probably want the jQuery .prop function which is true or false, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.xRgn .xInner .col .xOB', function(event){
    clickedDiv = $(this);

    clickedDiv.parents('.col').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
    });

    clickedDiv.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly in Firefox, i'll test in other browsers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use

> $(this).removeAttr("checked");

or

> $(this).prop("checked", true);`

`$(this).attr("checked", false);` creates this: `<input type="checkbox" checked=false>`

The presence of the attribute `checked`, whatever its value, makes the checkbox checked.

[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) affects the attributes while [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) affects the properties.

---

I got this from the links:

> **Attributes vs. Properties**
>   The difference between *attributes* and *properties* can be important in specific situations. **Before jQuery 1.6**, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. **As of jQuery 1.6**, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

And this form the attr link:

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. **To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method.**